# Create keyboard shortcut within ZedGraph

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts, zedgraph

I've a  [winform](/questions/tagged/winform) application in which I draw curves with [zedgraph](/questions/tagged/zedgraph). I'd love to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to the `UnZoom` function (kind of *undo last zoom action*).

I can acheive this by right clicking => Click on the <kbd>Un-Zoom</kbd> in the ToolStripMenu. This is how I tried to bind the shortcut to the action:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Z))
    {
        handleUnzoomFromkeyboard();
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
private void handleUnzoomFromkeyboard()
{
    foreach (ToolStripItem toolStripItem in lineGraphControl1.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Cast<ToolStripItem>().Where(toolStripItem => toolStripItem.Name == "unzoom"))
    {
        toolStripItem.PerformClick();
        return;
    }
}
```

It works well if I have **already** displayed the `ContextMenuStrip` (ie: right click on the graph) but doesn't work if I didn't.

I've try to build the context menu using some `ContextMenuBuilder` without luck.

How can I do it?

Comment: Did you try to show programmatically the ContextMenuStrip ? Using the show method, then hide it.
The goal is to emulate a first display of the Menu.

Comment: @MaximeMangel it doesn't work :(